Oracle-14400 error but value entering partitioned column does map to partition
I have a problem with an insert I am attempting into an Oracle table called MACON. The table structure is below.
The issue I have is that when I attempt to insert a value into the MEASPART column, which is the partitioned column, I get an Oracle 14400 error 'inserted partition key does not map to any partition'.
The key is generated from a sequence that populates the MEASID column (the currval that I have generated for my session where I'm encountering this error is 6174327 but it has happened on other sessions previous to this, both for me and other users) and then the partition number is created by taking the modulus of this as follows:
:NEW.measpart := MOD(:NEW.measid,7);

For the value I have gotten from the sequence (6174327), I generated the MEASPART partition number as
MOD(6174327,7) = 5;

As can be seen within the table build code below, a partition exists that can handle a value of 5 so I am uncertain as to why this error is occurring. A check of
select partition_name,high_value from dba_tab_partitions where table_name='MACON';

shows the same information as is in the build script - partitions ranging from P0 to P6 with values of 0 to 6 allowed.
Could someone please advise me as to what may be going wrong that could be causing this ORA-14400 error as I am completely confused at this point as all my checks seem to indicate that this value should not be blocked from insert?
CREATE TABLE DSDBA.MACON
(
  MEASID    NUMBER(16)                          NOT NULL,
  ACNO      VARCHAR2(9 BYTE),
  DSETID    NUMBER(8),
  IPJREF    NUMBER(8),
  TOPRSREF  NUMBER(8),
  IRSREF    NUMBER(8),
  PRIMDPT   VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
  CRMTYP    VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
  CRM       VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
  QMREF     VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
  CHECKS    VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)                    NOT NULL,
  CRBY      VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)                  NOT NULL,
  MODBY     VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)                  NOT NULL,
  CREATED   DATE                                NOT NULL,
  MODIFIED  DATE                                NOT NULL,
  MEASPART  NUMBER
)
NOCOMPRESS 
TABLESPACE TS1A
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   1
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            NEXT             1M
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           )
LOGGING
PARTITION BY LIST (MEASPART)
(  
  PARTITION P0 VALUES (0)
    LOGGING
    NOCOMPRESS 
    TABLESPACE TS1B
    PCTFREE    10
    INITRANS   1
    MAXTRANS   255
    STORAGE    (
                INITIAL          64K
                NEXT             1M
                MINEXTENTS       1
                MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
                BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
               ),  
  PARTITION P1 VALUES (1)
    LOGGING
    NOCOMPRESS 
    TABLESPACE TS1B
    PCTFREE    10
    INITRANS   1
    MAXTRANS   255
    STORAGE    (
                INITIAL          64K
                NEXT             1M
                MINEXTENTS       1
                MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
                BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
               ),  
  PARTITION P2 VALUES (2)
    LOGGING
    NOCOMPRESS 
    TABLESPACE TS1B
    PCTFREE    10
    INITRANS   1
    MAXTRANS   255
    STORAGE    (
                INITIAL          64K
                NEXT             1M
                MINEXTENTS       1
                MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
                BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
               ),  
  PARTITION P3 VALUES (3)
    LOGGING
    NOCOMPRESS 
    TABLESPACE TS1B
    PCTFREE    10
    INITRANS   1
    MAXTRANS   255
    STORAGE    (
                INITIAL          64K
                NEXT             1M
                MINEXTENTS       1
                MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
                BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
               ),  
  PARTITION P4 VALUES (4)
    LOGGING
    NOCOMPRESS 
    TABLESPACE TS1B
    PCTFREE    10
    INITRANS   1
    MAXTRANS   255
    STORAGE    (
                INITIAL          64K
                NEXT             1M
                MINEXTENTS       1
                MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
                BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
               ),  
  PARTITION P5 VALUES (5)
    LOGGING
    NOCOMPRESS 
    TABLESPACE TS1B
    PCTFREE    10
    INITRANS   1
    MAXTRANS   255
    STORAGE    (
                INITIAL          64K
                NEXT             1M
                MINEXTENTS       1
                MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
                BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
               ),  
  PARTITION P6 VALUES (6)
    LOGGING
    NOCOMPRESS 
    TABLESPACE TS1B
    PCTFREE    10
    INITRANS   1
    MAXTRANS   255
    STORAGE    (
                INITIAL          64K
                NEXT             1M
                MINEXTENTS       1
                MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
                BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
               )
)
NOCACHE;

`

You might want to use a virtual column for measpart rather than a trigger. That would eliminate some possible points of failure, be easier to understand and a lot more performant. I'm guessing there's a problem in the trigger code that is resulting in a value other than 0-6.

You are trying to INSERT a value that isn't associated with a partition. You can manually alter the table and add the nee partition or enable auto list partition. It would be helpful to show your INSERt statement

Consider removing the MEASPART column and instead using a hash partition based on MEASID:
CREATE TABLE MACON
(
  MEASID    NUMBER(16)                          NOT NULL,
  ACNO      VARCHAR2(9 BYTE),
  DSETID    NUMBER(8),
  IPJREF    NUMBER(8),
  TOPRSREF  NUMBER(8),
  IRSREF    NUMBER(8),
  PRIMDPT   VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
  CRMTYP    VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
  CRM       VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
  QMREF     VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
  CHECKS    VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)                    NOT NULL,
  CRBY      VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)                  NOT NULL,
  MODBY     VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)                  NOT NULL,
  CREATED   DATE                                NOT NULL,
  MODIFIED  DATE                                NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY HASH(MEASID) PARTITIONS 8;

Oracle will automatically derive the partition based on the value of MEASID. There will be no need for a trigger to set any values, and no need for users to remember to query with a MOD function. Partition pruning will happen with simple predicates, as you can see in the below example where the Pstart and Pstop reference only one partition:
explain plan for select * from macon where measid = 1;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display(format => 'basic +partition'));

Plan hash value: 747882418
 
-------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name  | Pstart| Pstop |
-------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |       |       |       |
|   1 |  PARTITION HASH SINGLE|       |     8 |     8 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL   | MACON |     8 |     8 |
-------------------------------------------------------

On the other hand, have you considered why you are partitioning at all? Usually, partitioning should be based on some intuitive way of querying for a large percentage of data. Something like, "get all the data for one year". Just partitioning on "anything" will likely only make your performance worse.

It works fine for the given mod function and it loads into the table just fine.
When the values is more than 6 it fails to insert.
Given below is a sample insert stmt that works.
insert into MACON  values(1,123456789,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,'Y','testing','testing',sysdate,sysdate,MOD(6174327,7)); 


Problem solved. Was indeed a problem in the trigger code. Minor tweak and everything now working.
